# If you have a class with many methods/constructors, is it better to create a new one if you just want to populate its properties?

Tags: c#, .net-core

If we have a class with many methods and maybe constructors, is it more taxing to be creating instances from it, rather than simply creating an object having the same properties and values from a different class?

To clarify: we are not using any methods, or special constructors from the class (we are using the default) when creating instances. We are only setting its properties/fields.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by *"is it more taxing to be creating instances"*. Could you be a bit more specific what exactly you're wondering about?

Comment: @germi exactly that. Because the class is filled with methods we are not using and constructors, does it hinder our performance? We're just calling the default constructor of the object and that's the end of it.

Comment: @SpiritBob if you are never using the methods and stuff, just remove them ?

Comment: @Cid in this example we can't remove them, hence the question.

Comment: Can you even modify the class that contains the methods ?

Comment: *"does it hinder our performance*" - what performance? Are you asking whether it's more costly (costs to be defined) to instantiate a "big" (whatever that means) object than it is to instantiate multiple small ones? That's easy: test it for yourself. You know best what performance is acceptable for your use case. For performance measuring I suggest you use something like [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet).

Comment: @Cid No. Imagine it being in a sandbox. Is that sandbox's unnecessary contents hindering us, to the point of making it worth creating a new class with the bare minimum, or not?

Comment: @SpiritBob then keep it as is. You could eventually have moved the properties to another class and makes the one that contains methods and stuff inherit from this one, but since you can't edit the original classes, don't make copy of the class elsewhere. [DRY !](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: @germi I'm hoping someone here can shine some light about that, yes. If it takes more time (not something like x1.07/x1.15 of the alternative), obviously it hinders performance.

Comment: I doubt that having 10 classes with 1 method is less "taxing" than having 1 class with 10 methods. Memory usage is defined by data you assigned. And code is compiled by JIT at the time of usage.

Comment: What you *may* earn in performance, you'll lose in maintainability

Comment: And this is just an oxymoron - *"creating the same instance from a different class"*. How can you achieve this?

Comment: @T.S. I think he meant *creating 2 objects having the same properties and values from differents classes*, which comes back to my previous comment : [DRY !](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: @T.S.yes, what Cid said.

Comment: @SpiritBob this is a bad practice, IMHO

Comment: @Cid I agree hence the question.

Comment: @SpiritBob The only time I would have 2 different classes with same properties is in Web Api. One will be facing client and another - database. To avoid over/under posting. But even then, they will be slightly different.

Comment: @T.S. thank you for the information! I do that as well. Do you try to filter out the "useless" information, by creating not 1 object for clients, but multiple, or you just generalize it under 1 object for the clients?

Comment: @SpiritBob What I mean, if I have web api model `user`, this model doesn't have property `password`. But DB-facing POCO does have. When admin queries web api for users, no way password is part of its return JSON.

Comment: @T.S. I understand you fully! But do you try to not return "useless" information to the client when doing so? If `user` has `Name` property, but the endpoint the client hits is something like `GetUserByName` - would you omit the `Name` property for the returned object (as it can be inferred from the endpoint itself), or do you just keep it all together? That's what I mean "useless" information. Information that for a specific endpoint might be redundant.

Comment: @T.S. As far as I know you can do the omitting either by creating a new class, or by using anonymous objects on return (though if you're relying on JsonPropertyName attributes you can't use anonymous objects.)

Comment: @SpiritBob No. If user hits endpoint with a valid criteria, you return entire model. That would be crazy not to. Physically, it is possible. Example - SSN. if the requestor has no access to SSN, you just show last 4 digits always. And the one that will have access to it, should have another route - `getssn/{id}`. This ways SSN always secured with authorized users having access to a special route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is <s>yes</s> **it depends ?**, even though it is not much.
as you can see it [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/optimization)
The less useless code there is in your methods, classes and so on the better.
It's the same for depth etc.
if you're really interested in this kind of tiny optimization, I highly recommend you to check this website and all the different benchmarks, even though i guess there are some tests with bias, it gives you a rough idea and you can do your own tests according to that.

**edit**: ok so it's right that there is not this exact case on the website so I recreated it myself. And the results are quite disturbing (I'm using console .Net framework 4.6.1)

first a light class with only the essential:

```
public class Light
    {
        private readonly int innervar;

        public Light(int _innervar)
        {
            innervar = _innervar;
        }

        public int usefulMethod(int param)
        {
            int tmp;

            tmp = innervar * innervar / innervar + innervar * param;

            return tmp;
        }
    }
```

then the same one but with useless functions and parameter everywhere.

```
class Heavy
    {
        private int innervar;
        private string uselessString;
        private float uselessFloat;

        public Heavy(int _innervar)
        {
            innervar = _innervar;
        }

        public Heavy(string _uselessString)
        {
            uselessString = _uselessString;
        }

        public Heavy(float _uselessFloat)
        {
            uselessFloat = _uselessFloat;
        }

        public int usefulMethod(int param)
        {
            int tmp;

            tmp = innervar * innervar / innervar + innervar * param;

            return tmp;
        }

        public int usefulMethod(float param)
        {
            int tmp;

            tmp = innervar * innervar / innervar + innervar * (int)param;

            return tmp;
        }

        public int usefulMethod(double param)
        {
            int tmp;

            tmp = innervar * innervar / innervar + innervar * (int)param;

            return tmp;
        }

        public int uselessMethod1()
        {
            int tmp;

            tmp = innervar * innervar / innervar + innervar;

            return tmp;
        }

        public int uselessMethod2()
        {
            int tmp;

            tmp = innervar * innervar / innervar + innervar;

            return tmp;
        }

        public int uselessMethod3()
        {
            int tmp;

            tmp = innervar * innervar / innervar + innervar;

            return tmp;
        }

        public int uselessMethod4()
        {
            int tmp;

            tmp = uselessprivate1(innervar);

            return tmp;
        }

        private int uselessprivate1(int tmp)
        {

            tmp = innervar * innervar / innervar + innervar;

            return tmp;
        }

        private int uselessprivate2(int tmp)
        {

            tmp = innervar * innervar / innervar + innervar;

            return tmp;
        }
    }
```

And here is the main test code that will call the 2 different classes:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            {
                var light = new Light(i);
                for (int y = 1; y < 1000000; y++)
                {
                    light.usefulMethod(y);
                }
            }

            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Light: " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            var watch2 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
            {
                var heavy = new Heavy(i);
                for (int y = 1; y < 1000000; y++)
                {
                    heavy.usefulMethod(y);
                }
            }
            watch2.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Heavy: " + watch2.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            var watch3 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                var light = new Light(i);
                for (int y = 1; y < 100; y++)
                {
                    light.usefulMethod(y);
                }
            }

            watch3.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Light: " + watch3.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            var watch4 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                var heavy = new Heavy(i);
                for (int y = 1; y < 100; y++)
                {
                    heavy.usefulMethod(y);
                }
            }
            watch4.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Heavy: " + watch4.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

And then the result that every time U run the program seem to be consistent ans quite counterintuitive. I also tried to add a sleep at the begining to avoid as much possible slow down due to the programm startup.

> Light: 2236
>   Heavy: 1608
>   Light: 1660
>   Heavy: 1537

So in the end theses results are quite disturbing. I encourage you to try on your machine, but I'll definetly dig deeper on my side too.

**Edit 2:**
I tried the above solution by removing the possible bias.
I made sure that none of the code is ignore at compile time by using first all the functions in heavy at least once.
Then I also only tried the method inside and not the instantation.
there is the nex version of the main:

```
var light2 = new Light(125);
var watch3 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (int y = 1; y < 500000000; y++)
{
    light2.usefulMethod(y);
}

watch3.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Light: " + watch3.ElapsedMilliseconds);

var heavy2 = new Heavy(125);
heavy2.uselessMethod1();
heavy2.uselessMethod2();
heavy2.uselessMethod3();
heavy2.uselessMethod4();
var watch4 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (int y = 1; y < 500000000; y++)
{
    heavy2.usefulMethod(y);
}
watch4.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Heavy: " + watch4.ElapsedMilliseconds);
Console.ReadKey();
```

And now there are the expected results:

> Light: 6603
>   Heavy: 6807

**Edit 3:**

So there is only the instanciation only test:

```
for (int it = 1; it < 10; it++)
{ 
    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 1; i < 50000000; i++)
    {
        var light1 = new Light(i);
    }

    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Light " + it + ": " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    var watch2 = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    for (int i = 1; i < 50000000; i++)
    {
        var heavy1 = new Heavy(i);
    }
    watch2.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Heavy " + it + ": " + watch2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

and there are the results, these ones seem way more constant:

> Light 1: 939
>   Heavy 1: 985
>   Light 2: 668
>   Heavy 2: 709
>   Light 3: 665
>   Heavy 3: 704
>   Light 4: 741
>   Heavy 4: 898
>   Light 5: 670
>   Heavy 5: 709
>   Light 6: 643
>   Heavy 6: 690
>   Light 7: 628
>   Heavy 7: 689
>   Light 8: 649
>   Heavy 8: 718
>   Light 9: 651
>   Heavy 9: 689

**edit 4:** After decompiling the abose code, now I know that even if you don't use functions they will be compiled. In my results even without using most of `Heavy`'s methods, everything was still compilated. using [dotPekk](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/decompiler/dotPeek_Getting_Started.html) and making sure to :

> clear the Use sources from symbol files when available checkbox on the
>   Decompiler page of dotPeek options

Comment: Where does it say in the link that less methods in your class is faster? All I can read about less code in methods is one benchmark about unused code in a method being more expensive (with the explanation that the unused code still forces variables to be created in memory even if they are never used), but that does not answer this question. That said, it's an interesting link.

Comment: Maybe you're right i'm doing a benchmark rn, to be sure i'll keep you updated

Comment: This is very helpful, but you're measuring invocations of a method, rather than the instantiating of light versus heavy objects. Could you tune your for loops so that they  instead instantiate a new object and just invoke the useful method? (No need to pre-burn useless methods, as in my original question we never invoke them.) That way we can compare how costly it is to instantiate a light vs heavy object.

Comment: If I pre-burn the useless methods, it's just to ensure that the compiler doesn't ignore it since it's never used elsewhere. for the instanciating let's see

Comment: Thank you! It seems there's no performance penalties/differences at all.